# How to set card elevation in jetpack compose with Material3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-cardview, android-compose-card

I've created the simple card in jetpack compose, Here I set elevation but it shows a type mismatch.

```
Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),elevation = 10.dp
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)) {
                Image(painter = painter, contentDescription = contentDescription,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
            }

    }
```

[image: An image of an error appearing in an editor. The error reads, "Type mismatch. Required: CardElevation. Found: Dp."]

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You are using **M3** (`androidx.compose.material3`) `Card` and the `elevation` attribute requires a **`CardElevation`** object:

Something like:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
        defaultElevation = 10.dp
    )
)
```

Comment: it changes the container color as well for some reason

Comment: Surface color will change depending on the elevation (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#elevation). See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160786

Comment: @user924 the color would have changed because you might have set the modifier field of that card to max width, due to which the card is taking the entire place of parent container and showing its default color, which Renaud Cerrato correctly mentioned would depend on elevation.

Answer (score 5):

We can use the following way to give elevation to card in Android compose

```
Card(elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
    defaultElevation = 10.dp))
```

And import

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Card(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
       shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
       elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
      defaultElevation = 5.dp))
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this syntax :

Card (elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(10.dp))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).